# How to make the effective date to start on a holiday/weekend in py QuantLib?

Tags: programming, quantlib

I'm trying to price a non-standard swap. However, my schedule is not returning the correct dates. In particular, the effective date starts on a Saturday but the schedule returns the next biz date which is a Monday. I need to accrual to start on the effective date without adjustment. How can I tell the schedule object to not do that?

Below is my code.

```
fixed_leg_schedule = ql.Schedule(
                    ql.Date(26, ql.September, 2020), 
                    ql.Date(25, ql.September, 2026), 
                    ql.Period('1M'), 
                    ql.UnitedStates(), 
                    ql.ModifiedFollowing, 
                    ql.ModifiedFollowing, 
                    ql.DateGeneration.Backward, 
                    False, 
                    ql.Date(15, ql.October, 2020), 
                    ql.Date(15, ql.September, 2026)
)
```

The 26th of Sept. 2020 is a Saturday, but the schedule returns 28th.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing `ql.ModifiedFollowing` you're telling the library to adjust non-business days based on that convention. If you don't want them adjusted, pass `ql.Unadjusted` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.